# Magento 2.3 Warning: Declaration of MGS\Amp\Block\Html\Topmenu

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error, setup-di-compile

I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Declaration of MGS\Amp\Block\Html\Topmenu::_getHtml(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, array $colBrakes = Array) should be compatible with Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::_gethtml(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass, $limit, $colBrakes = Array) in /var/www/vhosts/fakedomain.com/httpdocs/app/code/MGS/Amp/Block/Html/Topmenu.php on line 105
```

I get this error when trying to run the command - bin/magento setup:di:compile

I am trying to do this because even after I have the theme installed when i got to the home page i get an error. Those logs are saying:

```
Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:13313:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/fakedomain.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95):
```

Any help would be appreciated in this.

> EDIT:

here is the code from that file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MGS\Amp\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Html page top menu block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    /**
     * Cache identities
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected function _getHtml(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        array $colBrakes = []
    ) {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
        $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

        $counter = 1;
        $itemPosition = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $child */
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($childLevel === 0 && $child->getData('is_parent_active') === false) {
                continue;
            }
            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $currentClass = $child->getClass();

                if (empty($currentClass)) {
                    $child->setClass($outermostClass);
                } else {
                    $child->setClass($currentClass . ' ' . $outermostClass);
                }
            }

            if (is_array($colBrakes) && count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
                $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
            }

            if($this->_addSubMenu(
                $child,
                $childLevel,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $limit
            )) {
                $html .= '<amp-accordion ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
                $html .= '<section><h6>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                        $child->getName()
                    ) . '</h6>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                        $child,
                        $childLevel,
                        $childrenWrapClass,
                        $limit
                    ) . '</section></amp-accordion>';
            } else {
                $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                        $child->getName()
                    ) . '</span></a>';
            }

            $itemPosition++;
            $counter++;
        }

        if (is_array($colBrakes) && count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
            $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code from that file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace MGS\Amp\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\TreeFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Html page top menu block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu
{
    /**
     * Cache identities
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected function _getHtml(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
        $childrenWrapClass,
        $limit,
        array $colBrakes = []
    ) {
        $html = '';

        $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
        $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
        $childLevel = $parentLevel === null ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

        $counter = 1;
        $itemPosition = 1;
        $childrenCount = $children->count();

        $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
        $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $child */
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            if ($childLevel === 0 && $child->getData('is_parent_active') === false) {
                continue;
            }
            $child->setLevel($childLevel);
            $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
            $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
            $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

            $outermostClassCode = '';
            $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

            if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
                $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
                $currentClass = $child->getClass();

                if (empty($currentClass)) {
                    $child->setClass($outermostClass);
                } else {
                    $child->setClass($currentClass . ' ' . $outermostClass);
                }
            }

            if (is_array($colBrakes) && count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
                $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
            }

            if($this->_addSubMenu(
                $child,
                $childLevel,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                $limit
            )) {
                $html .= '<amp-accordion ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
                $html .= '<section><h6>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                        $child->getName()
                    ) . '</h6>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
                        $child,
                        $childLevel,
                        $childrenWrapClass,
                        $limit
                    ) . '</section></amp-accordion>';
            } else {
                $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
                        $child->getName()
                    ) . '</span></a>';
            }

            $itemPosition++;
            $counter++;
        }

        if (is_array($colBrakes) && count($colBrakes) && $limit) {
            $html = '<li class="column"><ul>' . $html . '</ul></li>';
        }

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove this answer as I've updated your question with this file content.